# State of the redux store is not being updated

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am working on a calculator using MERN stack but my client and server are different projects. React App is running on 3030 and Node Backend on 3000. I am able to retrieve the correct response from Node Backend, but not able to update it to the store, mostly due to the issue with the scope of 'state' or returned data. Below is my code snippet :

```
    const calcReducer = (state = calcState, action) => {     
    switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_ELEM':                 
          return {
              ...state,                            
              value: state.value == 0 ? action.text : state.value + action.text
          }       
    case 'CLEAR':
        return{
            ...state,
            value: 0
        }
    case 'EQUAL':

    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/calculate';                
    superagent
     .post(url)
     .send({ exp : state.value })         
     .set('Accept', 'application/json')
     .end((err,data) => {
        if (err)
          return state;
        else {                  
              console.log(state); //prints the old value of the state
              //below prints the correct state value but returning the state from here doesn't work
              console.log({ 
                ...state,
                value : Number(JSON.parse(data.text).result)
              })                                    
        }
      }) 
      return {
        ...state,
        value : VALUE // how can the value be brought here from inside of else loop
      }

    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

console.log statement inside 'else' prints correctly but no effect if I return state value from there. The place from where I am currently returning 'state' is not working out for me, and the returned state is exactly same as the state before the control came inside the case. Can someone please explain me how to work with the scope as I am new to ES6?

Edit1:

When I try to take the 'async-ness' out of the reducer, and make change as given below:

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return{
      value: state.value,
      btns: state.btns
   }
 }
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return{

    addElem: (text) => {

    dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_ELEM',
    text
  })
},

clear: () => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'CLEAR'
  })
},

equal: (value) => {
console.log(value)
superagent
 .post('http://localhost:3000/calculate')
 .send({ exp : value })         
 .set('Accept', 'application/json'))
 .end((err,data) => {              
       dispatch({ type: 'EQUAL', JSON.parse(data.text).result })                                 
      })
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, code build fails saying:
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (74:2)

```
   72 | 
   73 | const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 > 74 |   return{
      |   ^
   75 |     value: state.value,
   76 |     btns: state.btns
   77 |   }
```

Comment: You are trying to do some asynchronous operations, with side effects, inside your reducer. This is absolutely the opposite of what needs to be done. I suggest you read the documentation before using it http://redux.js.org/

Comment: I can understand that probably it's not the best approach to take and I am going through redux tutorials and documentation right now, but I'd like to know if this is really the scope issue, and can it be resolved easily using variables that span the scope of the 'case statement' in this context?

Comment: No problem, the issue is : Your reducer is synchronous, it take a state, an action, and have to return the new state immediatly. This is not just a problem of scope but a problem of time, your callback `.end((err,data) => ` will be executed a long time after the `return` of your reducer. Try to dispatch synchronous action outside of your reducer.
`superAgent.post().end(value => store.dispatch({ type: EQUAL, value })`, and have a look to http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncFlow.html

Comment: That's a nice trick but there again I am facing the same issue, when I perform 'dispatch' from inside of the callback, it is not really happening and the code build fails, I'll update the code above.

Comment: This is a syntax error, check your code again

Comment: I made you an answer with the corrected code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your `mapDispatchToProps`, try to well indent your code so it will be more easy to identify them.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {    
    addElem: (text) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_ELEM',
        text
      })
    },
    clear: () => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'CLEAR'
      })
    },
    equal: (value) => {
      console.log(value)
      superagent
       .post('http://localhost:3000/calculate')
       .send({ exp : value })         
       .set('Accept', 'application/json')
       .end((err,data) => {              
         dispatch({ type: EQUAL, result: JSON.parse(data.text).result })
       })
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The return statement is within a callback function. So, you are returning only from the callback function. You probably should wrap it in a Promise as follows.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  superagent(...)
  ...
  .end((err, data) => {
    if (err)
      reject(state);
    else {                  
      resolve({
        ...state,
        value : Number(JSON.parse(data.text).result)
      });                                    
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The author has edited the question, making my answer partly irrelevant! The original question tried to return from a callback.